# Macro for Texstudio to select like Rstudio

Tags: texstudio, rstudio

How can I set a macro to select a word in Texstudio **without the whitespace** after the word?

By Ctrl+Shift+Arrow (left, right) I get the word + whitespace.

I would like to select only the word and in the next hit get the whitespace(s) (more than one whitespace if it would be the case).

```
%SCRIPT
if (!cursor.hasSelection()) {
    cursor.select(cursorEnums.WordUnderCursor)
} else { 
    cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.NextWord, cursorEnums.KeepAnchor)
}
```

In the first word it goes for both directions, I wanted to the right and to the left separately.

Just to illustrate the Rstudio editor have this (wanted) behave.

Thanks!